# Как вывести данные из MySQL в ListView?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Есть база MySQL, я к ней подключился + вывел столбцы в "консоль" Android Studio, подскажите, как мне их вывести в ListView или что-нибудь на подобии него.

Код подключения и вывода:

```
// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://10.10.61.171:3306/Priem_zayvok";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "GLAZIK";
static final String PASS = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Zayavka";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            int id  = rs.getInt("id");
            String age = rs.getString("polzovatel");


            //Display values
            System.out.print("id: " + id);
            System.out.print(", polzovatel: " + age);

        }
        rs.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        }// do nothing
        try{
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

}

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот код выполнялся в Android-приложении или вы в Android Studio десктопное приложение разрабатываете?

Comment: Нет, мобильное приложение, я вот и хочу протестить на мобильном приложении, но для этого мне надо вывести в ListView. А что, с помощью этого кода у меня не получится вывести на мобильное?

Comment: TILL, Step2 и Step3 лучше вынести в отдельные методы, так код будет более читабелен

Comment: драйвер грузить не надо, все равно он автоматически подгружается по соответствующему интерфейсу, а вот обработчик ошибок всегда надо выбрасывать наружу.

Comment: И лучше использовать try с ресурсами - `try(stmt = conn.createStatement()){...}catch{...}`, тогда поток будет закрываться автоматически и блок `finally` не нужен будет

Comment: Ааа, хорошо, а как мне результат в ListView вывести?

Comment: Дело в том, что у Android-приложения совершенно другая структура исполнения. В нем нет точки входа `main()`, а есть стартовая активити с методами жизненного цикла, поэтому, прежде чем озадачиваться выводом чего то из MySQL в ListView стоит узнать хоть что то о разработке приложений для android. Данный код в таком виде, как в вопросе, никаким чудесным образом не будет выполняться в android-приложении, а объяснять общие основы разработки в назначение этого ресурса  не входит. Рекомендую почитать книжку Б.Филлипс "Android. программирование для профессионалов" 3-е издание для старта.